# C# Threading.Timer only ticks once

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

Very puzzled about timers, they don't seem to be working correctly.

I've created a timer like this:

`this._catTimer = new Timer(state => this.catTimer_Tick(null, new EventArgs()), null, 0, Timeout.Infinite);`

It ticks once immediately. At the end of the callback I have this:

`this._catTimer.Change(5000, Timeout.Infinite);`

But my timer never ticks again. This line is reached.

I've tried it with `5000, 0` too but it never ticks again. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are giving Timeout.Infinite for the period argument in both constructor [(public Timer(TimerCallback callback, Object state, uint dueTime, uint period))](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1cy0c7zw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Change(   int dueTime, int period)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz1c7148%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which mean you never want the periodic signalling.

*period*

> The time interval between invocations of the callback method specified
>   when the Timer was constructed, in milliseconds. Specify
>   Timeout.Infinite to disable periodic signaling, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz1c7148%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a try/catch around the logic in catTimer_Tick method. Maybe your code is never reaching .Change line.

Answer (score 0):

Have fixed this, it was caused by another thread that was blocking. You'd not think a threading timer would be affected by this but it was.

Comment: How were the threads synchronized? Did they use the same SynchronizationObject?